# Dynamically Naming Groups in Python Regular Expressions

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

Is there a way to dynamically update the name of regex groups in Python?

For example, if the text is:

```
person 1: name1
person 2: name2
person 3: name3
...
person N: nameN
```

How would you name groups 'person1', 'person2', 'person3', ..., and 'personN' without knowing beforehand how many people there are?

Comment: what is it that you are actually wanting to find from your sample text?

Comment: I'm trying to find the names of the people in something of a log file, which also contains other information that I'm parsing out (date, id, etc.). I was trying to do it all in one regex and end up with a dictionary of key/value pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can do something like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile('(?m)^(.*?)\\s*:\\s*(.*)$')
>>> text = '''person 1: name1
person 2: name2
person 3: name3
...
person N: nameN'''
>>> p.findall(text)
```

output:

```
[('person 1', 'name1'), ('person 2', 'name2'), ('person 3', 'name3'), ('person N', 'nameN')]
```

A quick explanation:

```
(?m)     # enable multi-line mode
^        # match the start of a new line
(.*?)    # un-greedily match zero or more chars and store it in match group 1
\s*:\s*  # match a colon possibly surrounded by space chars
(.*)     # match the rest of the line and store it in match group 2
$        # match the end of the line
```

References

- multi-line mode: http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html
- greedy/ungreedy matching: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html
- match groups http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer - what this regex does?

Answer (score 1):

named capture groups and numbered groups (\1, \2, etc.) cannot be dynamic, but you can achieve the same thing with findall:

> [re.findall(pattern, string[, flags])](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)
>
> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of
>   strings. The string is scanned
>   left-to-right, and matches are
>   returned in the order found. If one or
>   more groups are present in the
>   pattern, return a list of groups; this
>   will be a list of tuples if the
>   pattern has more than one group. Empty
>   matches are included in the result
>   unless they touch the beginning of
>   another match.

Answer (score 1):

judging from your accepted answer, there's no need for regex

```
p="""
person 1: name1
person 2: name2
person 3: name3
person N: nameN
"""

ARR=[]
for item in p.split("\n"):
    if item:
        s=item.split(":")
        ARR.append(s)
print ARR
```

output

```
$ ./python.py
[['person 1', ' name1'], ['person 2', ' name2'], ['person 3', ' name3'], ['person N', ' nameN']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Regexes in Python (and I'm pretty certain that that's true for regexes in general) don't allow for an arbitrary number of matches. You can either capture a repeated match in its entirety (by placing capturing parentheses around a repeated group) or capture the last match in a series of matches (by repeating a capturing group). This is independent of whether these are named or numbered capturing groups.

You need to do this programmatically by iterating over all matches in a string, like

```
for match in re.findall(pattern, string):
    do_something(match)
```